# Signal based CAN bus frame manipulation in C

Tags: python, c, arm, can-bus

I'm trying to manipulate a CAN signal using C (with a PCAN Router interface).

What the program does is waits for a CAN specific frame like 0x1F0 and then modify some bits. The bits I want to modify is based on a DBC file. So im trying to make it more dynamically by using [cantools](https://pypi.org/project/cantools/) to generate a source code a .h & .c file based on a DBC file here it's an example [motohawk.h](https://github.com/cantools/cantools/blob/master/tests/files/c_source/motohawk.h) and [motohawk.c](https://github.com/cantools/cantools/blob/master/tests/files/c_source/motohawk.c).

Link to the [motor DBC file](https://github.com/cantools/cantools/blob/master/tests/files/dbc/motohawk.dbc).

What I wish is to be able to manipulate a signal somehow like this.

So the question is how do I use the source to manipulate a signal signal? for example the Temperature signal? Maybe I'm seeing it wrong and it's not possible to do what I wish to.

Frame from DBC:

```
BO_ 496 ExampleMessage: 8 PCM1
 SG_ Temperature : 0|12@0- (0.01,250) [229.52|270.47] "degK"  PCM1,FOO
 SG_ AverageRadius : 6|6@0+ (0.1,0) [0|5] "m" Vector__XXX
 SG_ Enable : 7|1@0+ (1,0) [0|0] "-" Vector__XXX
```

What I want to do is to have a struct similar to this:

```
struct motohawk_example_message_t {
    /**
     * Range: -
     * Scale: 1
     * Offset: 0
     */
    uint8_t enable;

    /**
     * Range: 0..50 (0..5 m)
     * Scale: 0.1
     * Offset: 0
     */
    uint8_t average_radius;

    /**
     * Range: -2048..2047 (229.52..270.47 degK)
     * Scale: 0.01
     * Offset: 250
     */
    int16_t temperature;

};
```

but I would like to have a possibility to use something like:

```
frame_1F0 = motohawk_example_message_t();
frame_1F0.temperature.value = 255.01;
```

the **frame_1F0.temperature.value** will populate the correct bit/bytes in the frame (in the PCAN is something like TxMsg.Data16[index] = some hex value). Has somebody done it? or do you know if it's possible to use the source generated by the cantools package to do it?

Here is the PCAN code

```
frame_1F0 = motohawk_example_message_t();

while (1)
    {
        CANMsg_t  RxMsg, TxMsg;
        
        
        // process messages from CAN1
        if ( CAN_UserRead ( CAN_BUS1, &RxMsg) != 0)
        {
            // message received from CAN1
            // catch ID 1F0h from CAN1 to modify data
            if ( RxMsg.Id == 0x1F0)
            {
                RxMsg.Id = 0x1E4;
                RxMsg.Type = CAN_MSG_STANDARD;
            }           

            // copy message
            TxMsg.Id   = RxMsg.Id;
            TxMsg.Type = RxMsg.Type;
            TxMsg.Len  = RxMsg.Len;
            frame_1F0.temperature.value = 255.01; // this should be TxMsg.Data[xxx] = 255.01. THIS is the hard part :/ 
            

            // send
            CAN_UserWrite ( CAN_BUS2, &TxMsg);
...
```

Comment: Not sure what your problem is exactly. Are you asking how to get the data from `frame_1F0` into `TxMsg.Data`?

Comment: more like how do I convert from decimal to a binary format and place in the right place according to the DBC file.

Comment: „placing in the right place“ is done by the generated code. You basically fill the struct and then call the …_pack function. That will output the binary data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code generated with cantools can be used to *convert* the binary data to structs where you can access the signals and vice versa.

In your case something like this should work

```
...
CANMsg_t  RxMsg, TxMsg;
struct motohawk_example_message_t frame_1F0;

motohawk_example_message_unpack(&frame_1F0, RxMsg.Data.Data8, RxMsg.Len);

int16_t encoded_temperature = motohawk_example_message_temperature_encode(255.01);

frame_1F0.temperature.value = encoded_temperature;

motohawk_example_message_pack(TxMsg.Data.Data8, &frame_1F0, TxMsg.Len);

...
```

*Typing this of the top of my head. The code may not compile out-of-the-box but I hope it helps to get the idea.*

---

In the generated source code, the `_pack` and `_unpack` functions can be used to convert from `_message` struct to binary data and back.

The `_encode` and `_decode` functions are used to convert the signals from their physical representation to their raw representation and back.

Comment: Niiiice... Thanks for you reply. Now I understand a little bit better. But now I'm have problems with a few other things. like 1. How do I assign the "fram_1F0 = motohawk_example_message_t();" Correctly? and 2.also RxMsg.Data does not exitst... there is like RxMsg.data8, data16 and data32...  maybe I should save the "RxMsg.data"/payload somewhere before parsing to the unpack/pack function ? any good examples on how I can do it? (sorry for being a newbie)

Comment: @mike_aze I have changed the code above. `Data8` should be used (the pack and unpack functions expect uint8 arrays). I have also changed the declaration of `frame_1F0` (before I was simply using your example code).